# how do I interpret patch output?

Tags: diff, patch

I am trying to manually apply some patches, and wonder if I am interpreting the last few lines correctly. Here they are:

```
patching file frameworks/opt/telephony/tests/telephonytests/src/com/android/internal    /telephony/gsm/UsimDataDownloadCommands.java
Hunk #1 succeeded at 651 with fuzz 2 (offset 21 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 404
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java      b/packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceMan
ager.java
|index 6600ae5..2ae6739 100644
|--- a/packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java
|+++ b/packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java
--------------------------
File to patch: smartcard-api.patch
```

was UsimDataDownloadCommands.java file patched ok? Fuzz means, the patch utility found the match for target string, but it was at a different line. Right?

What about PhoneInterfaceManager.java file? I do have this file in my directory. But I am not sure what to do with it as there is not associated reject file for me to use? What is the reference to line 404? Is that the line number in my patch? 
Thanks

Comment: for your question 1, indeed, "fuzzy" matching mode means that the original line was at line 651+/-21. for your question 2, yes 404 is the line in the patch, you should open your patch in an editor and verify which lines exactly it is, are you sure that PhoneInterfaceManager.java is really at the right place?

Comment: @armel-I will have to check the Lin number. I am applying the patch to a different version of the source. So most likely it is at a different line.